# primeNG TabView won't show content onInit

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, tabview, lib

Good morning,

I have a problem with the primeNG component TabView. I am trying to build a custom lib with primeNG as base. Therefore I have implemented a tabs component and a tab-item component

In my first try every content of the items was displayed in the last tab. I've read that instead of

```
tabs-component:
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="tab.header" *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index [selected]="i == 0"">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>

tab-item-component:
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I have to use ngTemplateOutlet

```
tabs:
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="tab.header" *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index [selected]="i == 0"">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tab.template"></ng-container>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>

tab-item:
<ng-template>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and in typescript:

```
export class TabsComponent {
  @ContentChildren(TabItemComponent) tabs!: QueryList<TabItemComponent>;
}

export class TabItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  header: string = "";

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef)
  template!: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

But since the changes to ngTemplateOutlet, the content of the default selected tab 0 won't display on startup, although you can see that the first tab is selected. You have to click on a tab to see the content.

Please help me, I'm loosing my mind over this.

Comment: What if you programatically select the first tab? ```<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="index">``` in the ngOnInit() of the tabview component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did it myself. You have to extend the ViewChild of the TemplateRef with a static option.

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true })
```

static - True to resolve query results before change detection runs, false to resolve after change detection. Defaults to false.

Thanks for your help